# Magento Cron Issues

Tags: magento-1.9, cron

Basically I have a plugin that needs to remind a user about a quote they created 2 days after they create it.

The plugin company says its a cron problem why it isn't working and has left it at that.

I installed AOE Scheduler which says there is No Heartbeat at the top.

Can anyone advise how I can sort out my crons so I don't get this error and hopefully get this plugin working?

Comment: Do you have a dedicated server or a support to contact?

Comment: Have you confirmed that your cron is setup for Magento?

Comment: http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/how_to_setup_a_cron_job

Comment: I can contact server support bu I am unusure what I am asking. In plesk I have the Magento cron to run every 5 minutes. What else can I check and how do I check it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not getting a heart beat with AOE scheduler it seems your cron is not properly setup. You will need to setup cron on the server with something like the following:

```
* * * * * /bin/sh /path/to/your/site/cron.sh
```

Once you have your "Heartbeat" you will see your cron items working